# Is there a way to get the envelope status from a specific envelope?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I am using Microsoft Power Automate and using the "When an envelope status changes (Connect) (V3)" connector to trigger my Flow when it is completed. Is there a way to track the envelope status from a specific envelope?

Currently, my Flow is triggered by any envelope is completed.

I have tried to utilize a Do Until loop with a condition to check for a specific envelope ID. This caused multiple Connect custom configurations to be created and maxed out the limit on API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same do loop but add a 15 min intervals. So you

1. Check status. If status is not yet complete, you:
2. Wait 15 minutes
3. Loop again back to 1.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/dataverse/wait-conditions explains how to do a delay in Power Automate.